# How to disables wordpress updates using hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I disables WordPress updates, plugins updates and themes updates using hooks. There are many plugins for unable updates but how can I do that with hooks.

Comment: Have you tried a google search? Plenty of results came up when I did a search.

Comment: You can define stop updates in the wp-config.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates

Comment: @AlexKante  Yes your answer is correct, but I am not looking for any plugin I need to do that via hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the class with hooks you just copy and paste in function.php. This code will disable your all updates (WordPress, plugins and theme).

```
/* The OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates class */
class OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates {
    private $__pluginsFiles;
    private $__themeFiles;

    function __construct() {
        $this->__pluginsFiles = array();
        $this->__themeFiles = array();

        add_action( 'admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init') );

        if( !function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';

        if( count( get_plugins() ) > 0 ) foreach( get_plugins() as $file => $pl ) $this->__pluginsFiles[$file] = $pl['Version'];
        if( count( wp_get_themes() ) > 0 ) foreach( wp_get_themes() as $theme ) $this->__themeFiles[$theme->get_stylesheet()] = $theme->get('Version');

        add_filter( 'pre_transient_update_themes', array($this, 'last_checked_themes') );

        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_themes', array($this, 'last_checked_themes') );

        add_action( 'pre_transient_update_plugins', array(&$this, 'last_checked_plugins') );

        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', array($this, 'last_checked_plugins') );

        add_filter( 'pre_transient_update_core', array($this, 'last_checked_core') );

        add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', array($this, 'last_checked_core') );

        add_filter( 'auto_update_translation', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_true' );
        add_filter( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'wp_auto_update_core', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'send_core_update_notification_email', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'automatic_updates_send_debug_email', '__return_false' );
        add_filter( 'automatic_updates_is_vcs_checkout', '__return_true' );


        add_filter( 'automatic_updates_send_debug_email ', '__return_false', 1 );
        if( !defined( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED' ) ) define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
        if( !defined( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE') ) define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );

        add_filter( 'pre_http_request', array($this, 'block_request'), 10, 3 );
    }

    function OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates() {
        $this->__construct();
    }

    function admin_init() {
        if ( !function_exists("remove_action") ) return;

        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
        remove_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'maintenance_nag' );
        remove_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'maintenance_nag' );

        remove_action( 'load-themes.php', 'wp_update_themes' );
        remove_action( 'load-update.php', 'wp_update_themes' );
        remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_themes' );
        remove_action( 'wp_update_themes', 'wp_update_themes' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_update_themes' );

        remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_themes' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_update_themes' );

        remove_action( 'load-plugins.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
        remove_action( 'load-update.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
        remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_plugins' );
        remove_action( 'wp_update_plugins', 'wp_update_plugins' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_update_plugins' );

        remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_update_plugins' );

        add_action( 'init', create_function( '', 'remove_action( \'init\', \'wp_version_check\' );' ), 2 );
        add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', '__return_null' );

        remove_action( 'wp_version_check', 'wp_version_check' );
        remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_core' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_version_check' );

        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_version_check' );

        remove_action( 'wp_maybe_auto_update', 'wp_maybe_auto_update' );
        remove_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_maybe_auto_update' );
        remove_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_auto_update_core' );
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wp_maybe_auto_update' );
    }


    public function block_request($pre, $args, $url) {}

    public function last_checked_core() {}

    public function last_checked_themes() {}

    public function last_checked_plugins() {}
}

if ( class_exists('OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates') ) {
    $OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates = new OS_Disable_WordPress_Updates();
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I was looking something like this. I think I can also create plugins by using this. Am I right? Can you please explain me a bit.

Comment: Yes, you can  create a plugins too. Just  follow the steps how to create a plugins it will work fine. Here is the link (https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)